# google MarkerImage shifting not working

Tags: google-maps, marker, shift

I have markers which use MarkerImage on my map.
The problem is I'm trying to shift the marker image so the icon centre is on the exact coordinate position.

I doesn't work.

My code is:

```
var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage(icon,
  // This marker is 15 pixels wide by 15 pixels tall.
  new google.maps.Size(15, 15), 
  new google.maps.Point(7,7),
  new google.maps.Point(7,7)
);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon),
  map: map,
  title: title,
  icon: icon
});
```

Markers should be centred on the polylines as they mark object which are located on polylines. They appear next to it on my map.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I had icon instead of image inserted in my marker so it didn't see the shifted image.

Besides MarkerImage has changed to Icon type in the reference since version 3.11 so it was worth amending too.